# Updating a method through a dynamic variable is not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following method, that works perfectly on class init (i.e `new car().filter(d => d.Color == "Red")`):

```
filter = (event) => {
    this.filter = event
    return this
}
```

I am trying to update it dynamically though a user changing a dropdown:

```
let colorDropdown = document.getElementById('colorDropdown');

colorDropdown.onchange = () => {
     let color = colorDropdown.value; 
     this.filter = d => d.Color == ""+color+"";
}
```

Saying a user selects "Orange", If I console log the aforementioned individually I get

```
console.log(color) = `Orange`
console.log(this.filter) = `d => d.Color == ""+color+""`
```

My problem stems from color remaining a variable in the "this.filter =" portion of my code. Maybe I am thinking of this incorrectly? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you actually seeing a bug with the behavior of your program? Or are you just confused why `console.log()` shows the variable `color` instead of its value?

Comment: @ShaneBishop why the console.log shows color instead of the value - I have yet to test whether or not it works because I figured it was a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is reached, the value of `color` is captured and stored as part of the arrow function. It is just a fact that when you `console.log()` an arrow function, that is how it is displayed. Your `color` variable will actually be defined when `this.filter` is executed.

The concept you are using is known as a "closure". For more details, refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for closures in JavaScript.

The code that you have provided should work as is. If there is a bug, it is likely a bug in code you did not include in your question.